# Excel Formula - Test Dates and Multiply Index

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good afternoon...

So I have all the values of inflation of each year... something like:

```
    A     B 
1 2011 0.4%
2 2012 0.6%
3 2013 0.5%
4 2014 0.8%
5 2015 3.0%
6 2016 2.0%
```

In another sheet I have the original value of the agreement and when it was signed by the parts...

Exemple:

```
      A           B        C
1 Contract A - 10/16/2013 - $30.000
2 Contract A -  Today -      VALUE
```

What I need to do is to check how much the owner of contract A should pay today w/ the inflation correction...

So I need to formulate something that checks every year of my inflation sheet and test if it should or should not multiply by that year inflation based on the year that the agreement was signed... if the agreement was signed 10/16/2013 it should use every inflation index from 2014(not before) until 2019.... and it will use the 2020 index When we arrive in October...

I’m thinking about use something with an “If” and a LOOKUPV but I still can’t figure out the whole formula... does anybody has any tip?

Comment: You have the base of $30.00 from 2013 which increased by 0.8% in 2014 becoming $30.24. That should increase by 3% in 2015 becoming $31.1472. Add 2% in 2016 = $31.770144 etc. A worksheet function could do one loop for you but for an unlimited number of loops you would require code, perhaps a UDF. The alternative would be an unlimited number of columns, one for each year. Imagine the contract ID in column A, $30.00 in column for 2013, $30.24 in column for 2014 etc. Columns prior to 2013 would be blank.

Comment: If I follow your tip, how would you automatize so excel knows that the last year value corresponds to 2019 and this year it should look for the following year index... or you would do it manually?

Comment: You would need the contract ID which you use VLOOKUP to find the date of. Are you thinking of multiple columns or UDF?

Comment: Need more information. What is the relation between the contract signing date and the first and last inflation year to be used?  What if the contract was signed on `1-Jan-2013` ?  What about `2-Jan-2013` ?  If today were 1 Feb 2020 do you really want to include the rate from 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a list of contracts which looked like this.

[image: Note that the contract IDs must be entered as Text]

Next, I created an inflation table as shown below.

[image: Inflation table]

Based on these two tables I developed a formula.

[image: Formula development]

The steps of development have been isolated and I hope this will help you make required modifications.  Below is a version of the formula intended for you to copy.

```
=IF(YEAR(VLOOKUP($A4,Contracts!$A$2:$B$1000,2,FALSE))<=B$3,(1+IF(ISNUMBER(A4),VLOOKUP(B$3,Inflation!$A$2:$B$25,2,FALSE),0))* IF(ISNUMBER(A4),A4,VLOOKUP($A4,Contracts!$A$2:$C$1000,3,FALSE)),"")
```

In the final picture you see the result. The above formula was lifted from cell B4. All other cells of the table have copies thereof.

[image]
Observe the component function `IF(ISNUMBER(A4), ...` In all columns except column B this test is carried out on a base value (the agreed contract price). Not allowing a number as contract ID shortens the formula. Here is the reason for this rule.

Comment: Hi, could you please help me on this link,    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448265/please-help-me-to-get-the-data-based-on-date-and-name-in-excel-sheet

Comment: @Naveen Your problem has a solution here: https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria. The formulas are explained superbly but as a newcomer to Excel you may find them demanding nevertheless. Don't feel discouraged. Don't waste time looking for something easier. There is no better way to learn than to have a full explanation. Study hard and you will succeed.

Comment: @ Variatus, Hope you could help me about the my query which is mentioned in the link.

Comment: This almost solves my problem!!! The only problem is that its does not check the MONTH when the Contract was Signed!!!!
So if it was signed 12/2019 this solution would increase the value in the next month, 01/2020 , before it really complete one year, but it should not. It should increase the value 12/2020

Comment: Exceljet explains how to do a lookup with multiple conditions. You have only two. Therefore you have a solution there but you must find the way to adapt it to your own problem. That's the way we all work and learn, not only you. But you probably did learn enough by now to qualify for asking a question that won't be closed. Just make sure to share the experience you already have. Asking for a solution requires someone to repeat the work you already did. You already have half a solution. Ask for the other half of the solution.